# How To Get Next JSON Item

Tags: javascript, json

I am wondering how would I get the next JSON item if I have the key in JavaScript. For example, if I provide the key 'Josh' how would I get the contents of 'Annie' along with the key 'Annie'? Would I have to process the JSON in an array and extract from there?

In addition, I believe that there is a proper term for transforming data from one type to another. Any chance anyone knows what it is... it is just on the tip of my tongue!

```
{
    "friends": {
        "Charlie": {
            "gender": "female",
            "age": "28"
        },
        "Josh": {
            "gender": "male",
            "age": "22"
        },
        "Annie": {
            "gender": "female",
            "age": "24"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not possible, properties in a JSON object do not have an order.

Comment: @leo.fcx, How does that make a difference ? OP is not concerned about the order!

Comment: "I believe that there is a proper term for transforming data from one type to another. " This is called type conversion, or [typecasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion)

Comment: @RayonDabre OP clearly states he is looking for the "next" JSON item

Comment: @Michael-R, May be I am reading it some other way!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In JavaScript the order of Object properties is not guaranteed ([ECMAScript Third Edition (pdf):](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf))

> 4.3.3 Object An object is a member of the type Object. It is an unordered collection of properties each of which contains a primitive
>   value, object, or function. A function stored in a property of an
>   object is called a method.

If the order doesn't have to be guaranteed you could do the following:

```
var t = {
    "friends": {
        "Charlie": {
            "gender": "female",
            "age": "28"
        },
        "Josh": {
            "gender": "male",
            "age": "22"
        },
        "Annie": {
            "gender": "female",
            "age": "24"
        }
    }
};

// Get all the keys in the object
var keys = Object.keys(t.friends);

// Get the index of the key Josh
var index = keys.indexOf("Josh");

// Get the details of the next person
var nextPersonName = keys[index+1];
var nextPerson = t.friends[nextPersonName];
```

If order matters I would recommend having another array of to hold the order of the names `["Charlie", "Josh", "Annie"]` instead of using `Object.keys()`.

```
var t = ...;

// Hard code value of keys to make sure the order says the same
var keys = ["Charlie", "Josh", "Annie"];

// Get the index of the key Josh
var index = keys.indexOf("Josh");

// Get the details of the next person
var nextPersonName = keys[index+1];
var nextPerson = t.friends[nextPersonName];
```

Comment: Is it also possible to get the key value of the next friend? So in your example, I would also like to get the value 'Annie' as well.

Comment: Ahh, great trick on storing the order in an array. That's exactly what I need. Thank you!

Comment: @Jon, I've updated the example to reflect getting the name of the next person

Comment: Oh, woops. i actually mis read your code. I cannot hard code the values of my keys as they are dynamically generated. I guess I will have to create an array to store these keys first.